# SQL Server / Entity Framework Core: is it better that parent have a child key as a foreign key for searching?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have following two models.

```cs
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamAddress TeamAddress { get; set; }
}

public class TeamAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Some seasons, `TeamAddress` has to have a key itself.

In this case, `TeamAddress` has a key of the `Team` but `Team` doesn't have a key of the `TeamAddress`.

With EF Core I don't need to care about it.

But I'm curious. `Team` doesn't have an ID of the `TeamAddress`. Doesn't it make to search (select query) when starts from `Team` class? (because I think `Team` has to use 'Join' for looking a `TeamAddress`)

Like

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Team AS T
INNER JOIN TeamAddress AS TA ON T.Id = TA.TeamId;
```

If the `Team` has an `ID` of `TeamAddress`, does it make better??

Comment: *If the Team has an ID of TeamAddress, does it make better??* - ***NO!!!!*** because **one team** most likely can have multiple team addresses - so the `ID` of which one of those addresses do you want to store on the `Team` entity?? The setup is correct - you have a `Team` with an `ID`, and any `TeamAddress` will **reference** that `Team.ID` and thus establish the 1:n relationship. That's the way it is **supposed to be** and it's good that way!

Comment: Usually the dependent in one-to-one relationship is modelled with the so called *shared primary key association*, where it has no separate FK, bur PK is also a FK. And as you can see, in that design the principal (what you call "parent") does not need a join for getting the "child" PK, because it is the same as its own PK.  Join is needed only when the dependent has separate FK as in your example. In both cases the principal cannot have FK to dependent, because that's against relational data principles.

Comment: @marc_s How can I search Team from TeamAddress and opposite?

Comment: @IvanStoev I want to access them by an object that have in their side. Like
'Team.TeamAddress.~' and
'TeamAddress.Team.~'